# Keyboard shorcuts don't work when laptop is connected to external keyboard or screen

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

I have a Thinkpad T440 and every time that I connect an external keyboard or screen, almost all of the shortcut keys stop work, like volume buttons, super and ctrl + alt + t. This started when I installed XFCE and happens with xubuntu, zorin OS and manjaro xfce. The only way to get the keys working again is by rebooting the computer and disconnecting the screen and keyboard.
I tried change the keyboard layout, but didn't work.

Comment: It looks like the X-org server is having problems. Care to share your dmesg and the changes of Xorg0.log?  Use tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log (only if X-server is running, not wayland)

Comment: dmesg -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log didn't work
error: dmesg: unknown facility '/var/log/Xorg.0.log'

Comment: now seems that my keyboard is broken. When I press a key, random characters are generated, like "Wos243".

Comment: these are two commands: "dmesg" shows the kernel stuff.....      if you want to follow a log file, you need to execute "tail -f /path/to/file.log"    So two different commands that show completely different things